# How select up or down in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In most text editors, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> selects everything behind the cursor on the current line and everything in front of the cursor on the line above. Likewise with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> except downwards.

I'm wanting to customize the shortcuts in VS to be those, but I can't find the corresponding field in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. In most IDEs (such as all JetBrains IDEs) what I'm looking for is called "Select Up" or something to that effect. Haven't been able to find anything similar in the list in VS. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with other IDEs but I think you might be looking for Shift + arrow-key?